# Importing a text file into Cassandra using Spark when there are multiple variable types

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark, cql, datastax-enterprise

I'm using Spark to import data from text files into CQL tables (on DataStax).  I've done this successfully with one file in which all variables were strings.  I first created the table using CQL, then in the Spark shell using Scala ran:

```
val file = sc.textFile("file:///home/pr.txt").map(line => line.split("\\|").map(_.toString));
file.map(line => (line(0), line(1))).saveToCassandra("ks", "ks_pr", Seq("proc_c", "proc_d"));
```

The rest of the files I want to import contain multiple variable types.  I've set up the tables using CQL and specified the appropriate types there, but how do I transform them when importing the text file in spark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example if proc_c is Int and proc_d is Double you can do it this way:

```
file.map{
   line => (line(0), line(1)).
           map({ case (l, r) => (l.toInt, r.toDouble) }).
           saveToCassandra("ks", "ks_pr", Seq("proc_c", "proc_d")
}
```

Comment: I believe there is a syntax error with your parentheses.  Are you intending to have a nested map?

Comment: I was able to solve my problem using this answer after fixing the parentheses.  The code I used successfully was: `file.map(line => (line(0), line(1), line(2), line(3), line(4), line(5), line(6)))
.map({ case (a, b, c, d, e, f, g) => (a.toInt, b.toString, c.toString, d.toString, e.toString, f.toString, g.toString) })
.saveToCassandra("ks", "ks_pr", Seq("proc_a","proc_b","proc_c","proc_d","proc_e","proc_f","proc_g"));`

Answer (score -1):

Use this for getting records from the txt file and storing into cassandra db:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Row;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;

public class App {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
    String serverIp = " ? ";
    String keyspace = "? ";
    String username=" ?";
    String password=" ? ";

    Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
                            .addContactPoints(serverIp)
                            .withCredentials(username.trim(), password.trim())
                            .build();
    Session session = cluster.connect(keyspace);
    File file = new File("E:\\new workspace\\Casandracheck3\\text1.txt");

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); 

    String st; 
    String mc_name=null;
    String mobileno=null;
    String customer_id=null;
    String date_time=null;
    Integer cust_id=0;
    while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {

      StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(st, ","); 

      mc_name = tokenizer.nextToken();
      mobileno = tokenizer.nextToken();
      customer_id=tokenizer.nextToken();
      date_time=tokenizer.nextToken();
      cust_id=Integer.parseInt(customer_id);

      System.out.println("USERNAME=" + mc_name + "&MOBILENO=" + mobileno + "&CUSTOMER_ID=" + cust_id + "&DATE_TIME=" + date_time);
      System.out.println("checking before queryy..............................");

      String cqlStatement = "insert  into table_name(id,mc_name,mc_mobileno,customer_id,mc_imported_date)"
            + "values(now(),'" + mc_name + "','" + mobileno + "'," + customer_id+ ",'"+date_time+"')";

      for (Row row : session.execute(cqlStatement)) {
        System.out.println(row.toString());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this for getting records from the txt file and storing into cassandra db

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. You should edit your answer and place this comment in it in order to make it more visible.

Comment: sorry to say, but this code is really very inefficient... It's better to use something like cassandra loader, etc.